# Openshift origin oc cluster up fails

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin

Using the last version of openshift origin `v3.10.0` i run the following command on centos VM:

`oc cluster up --public-hostname=192.168.56.15 --http-proxy=http://proxy.ip:port --https-proxy=https://proxy.ip:port --no-proxy=[192.168.56.0/24,172.0.0. 0/8,192.168.56.15,192.168.56.15,localhost]`

In result i get:

```
Getting a Docker client ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.10 is available ...
Checking type of volume mount ...
Determining server IP ...
Checking if OpenShift is already running ...
Checking for supported Docker version (=>1.22) ...
Checking if insecured registry is configured properly in Docker ...
Checking if required ports are available ...
Checking if OpenShift client is configured properly ...
Checking if image openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.10 is available ...
Starting OpenShift using openshift/origin-control-plane:v3.10 ...
I1003 10:58:00.643521    3446 flags.go:30] Running "create-kubelet-flags"
I1003 10:58:01.314805    3446 run_kubelet.go:48] Running "start-kubelet"
I1003 10:58:01.549316    3446 run_self_hosted.go:172] Waiting for the kube-apiserver to be ready ...
E1003 11:03:01.559324    3446 run_self_hosted.go:542] API server error: Get https://127.0.0.1:8443/healthz?timeout=32s: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8443: getsockopt: connection refused ()
Error: timed out waiting for the condition
```

And while following the log of docker i notice the following error:

```
E1003 github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/k8s.io/kubernetes/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go:452: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get https://localhost:8443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp [::1]:8443: getsockopt: connection refused
```

Which is a normal behavior since netstat shows only one port opened:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::10250                :::*                    LISTEN      3894/hyperkube
```

PS:

- As you can see i use proxy.
- I tried to use a local resolving, using dns instead of ip@ and since i don't have a DNS server i used /etc/hosts, same problem.

Comment: It appears that 3.9 work so well with the same configuration...